# SQL Query that identifies if a pattern recurs in a text field

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to do a query on a Japanese dictionary DB I created that identifies repeating words—words like ニコニコ (niko niko), ピカピカ (pika pika), etc.  While I know how to do `LIKE %%` queries, I'm not certain how to get it to define a pattern off one part and see if the other part matches it.

Parameters:

- All of the words I'm looking for are 4 double-byte characters long
- Pattern A consists of the first two characters, Pattern B consists of the last two
- The query is being run on a `headwords` table that is structured rather simply: It has two fields, `id` and `headword`
- Collation on the table is set to `utf8_bin`
- We want to filter to search only headwords that are 4 characters long, then identify Pattern A and see if Pattern B is identical.  If so, return the `id`.

**Bonus:** If there is a way to run the search as straight `utf8` instead of `utf8_bin`, that would be helpful for picking up some additional matches (e.g. つれづれ tsure dure).  The headwords column has a `UNIQUE` index on it, and requires `utf8_bin` collation to enforce the index properly for normal operations.

**Data & Result Example**
*Added per Strawberry's suggestion*

```
id | headword
=============
 1 | たべる
 2 | あらわれる
 3 | ばかばかしい
 4 | ニコニコ
 5 | じゅんびする
 6 | ぴかぴか
 7 | する
 8 | つれづれ
 9 | ひとびと
10 | ひと
```

Desired result would return `id`s `4` and `6`; an optimal result would also return `8` and `9`.

- `1` is too short by 1 character, and Pattern A (`たべ`) does not match Pattern B (`る`)
- `2` is too long by 1 character, and Pattern A (`あら`) does not match Pattern B (`われ`).  Ditto for `5`
- `3` has matches for Patterns A and B (`ばか`), however it's too long at 6 characters
- `7` and `10` are too short by 2 characters.  While there's a possible Pattern A (e.g. `ひと` in `10` appears in `ひとびと` in `9`), it's not long enough to provide a Pattern B to compare against

Comment: This isn't really what SQL is intended for.

Comment: I've done similar with PHP in the past, but brute-forcing it can take solid days of processing time with as many rows as I've got in the table, hence why I was hoping there was a way to do it all on the MySQL side, perhaps...

Comment: Are all the patterns two kana long?

Comment: Yes, all patterns are two kana long, and all results are a total of 4 kana long.

Comment: This is actually quite simple with a regex library which supports back references. Unfortunately, the MySQL library does not. That said, consider providing some actual data, and a desired result.

Comment: So this seems solvable. Just compare one substring with another

Comment: In PHP, this is what you are looking for:  `preg_match('/^(..)\1$/u', 'ニコニコ')` will be `true`.

Comment: @RickJames Tested that and it's working pretty well.  If you feel like fleshing that out into a full answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, this is what you are looking for: `preg_match('/^(..)\1$/u', 'ニコニコ')` will be `true`.

The `u` qualifier says that characters are utf8.
The `..` finds any 2 characters.
The `\1` is a back-reference to `(..)`, hence matching a duplicate.
The `^` and `$` 'anchor' the regexp to the start and end of the target string.
The `'ニコニコ'` is merely one of the test cases.

So, start at the beginning, find 2 utf8 characters, make sure they are immediately repeated, and nothing else follows.